# Change class style using jQuery slider UI

Tags: jquery, css, range, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to use the jQuery UI Slider to change a css3 style in my rotate class:

So on slide change 
`-webkit-animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;`

to

`-webkit-animation: rotate 0.1s linear infinite;`

0.1 being the highest value and 10s being the lowest

And need to do this for animation and -moz- for cross broswer compatiblity. Not sure how many steps here but 10 should work fine?

```
.rotate{ 
 background: url(images/rotate.png) no-repeat;
 position: absolute;
 width: 350px;
 height: 350px;
 margin: 0;
 left: -50px;
 top: -50px;
 -webkit-animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;
 animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: rotate 10s linear 0s infinite;
}
```

I found this code:

```
$(function() {
$('.slider').slider({
    value:0,
    min: 0,
    max: 9,
    slide: handleSliderChange
});

function handleSliderChange(event, slider){
          $('.rotate').css('width', slider.value + '%');
}
});
```

Comment: If you looking for rotation..you can check this out..http://jsfiddle.net/XtksX/2/

Comment: Hi, i am looking to use jquery ui slider to change the value in my css3 rotation so it spins faster as the slider goes up.